# DOMDocument get parent element by X has value PHP

Tags: php, dom

I have a HTML document with some html code.

Lets say its like this:

```
<div>
<div class="z">
<div><span class="x">Hey</span> </div>
</div>
<div class="z">
<div><span class="x">two</span> </div>
</div>
```

```
   $doc = new DOMDocument();
$doc->loadHTML('<?xml encoding="UTF-8">' . $response);


$savedhtml =  $doc->saveHTML();
```

Is there a way so i can get the parent element from element X class , where element X must contain a spesific value?

In this case. Find that class X has Hey, then return all child element of the Z that is the parent to Hey?

Answer (score 0):

Try this one

```
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div>
<div class="z">
<div><span class="x">Hey</span> </div>
</div>
<div class="z">
<div><span class="x">two</span> </div>
</div>
</div>


<script type="text/javascript">
    $(document).ready(function(){
        /*iterate through all elements having class z*/
        $('.z').each(function(i, obj) {
   /*getting its children elements correspondingly*/    
   a=$( obj ).children().html();
        alert($(a).html());
    });
});

</script>
```

Comment: That would work, but i need it PHP-sided. :| else, could it be an idea for PHP to send result to js and then send result back?

Comment: you can also call js from php like    echo "<script src=demo.js></script>";

Comment: similary which i mention in above comment you can also write full script in php echo